# Choose at GRUB menu whether NVidia driver should be used

Tags: drivers, grub2, elementary-os

For some games, I need the `nvidia-current` driver, but when it's enabled, I can't get my work done as [it messes up everything](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47875/graphics-problems-with-applications).
So is there a way I can get two options in my GRUB menu? One wich will load my operating system **with** the `nvidia-current` drivers, and one which will use the default *non-proprietary* one? It seems a bit stupid to me to have 2 Ubuntu installations (one for games, one for the rest). But I can't get my daily work done **with** the Nvidia drivers enabled as it messes up some applications, randomly freezes the system, etc. But I still want to be able to play some games.

If there's a way to just load and unload the `nvidia-current` driver with a script or something, that would also be welcome.

Answer (score 4):

You can prevent the nvidia driver from loading automatically be appending `modprobe.blacklist=nvidia-current` to your kernel line. If that does not help, try `nvidia` instead of `nvidia-current`.

Other than hard-coding the new kernel options for each kernel version, edit `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` and find the next line:

```
  linux_entry "${OS}" "${version}" false \
      "${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX} ${GRUB_CMDLINE_EXTRA} ${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT}" \
      quiet
```

Duplicate it and modify it to add the modprobe options:

```
  linux_entry "${OS} (no nvidia)" "${version}" false \
      "${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX} ${GRUB_CMDLINE_EXTRA} ${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT}" \
      quiet modprobe.blacklist=nvidia-current
```

Run `sudo update-grub` afterwards to generate the new boot configuration.

Comment: And will blacklisting the driver automatically enable the other one?

Comment: Do you mean `nouveau`?

Comment: `I guess so... robin@robin-Latitude-D620:~$ lsmod | grep nouveau | pastebinit
http://pastebin.com/KxqT6vv7`

Comment: Hello? Still there?

Comment: Yes, I thought you've already sorted it out. Did it work as expected?

Comment: Haven't tried yet because of that reason :p

Comment: This actuall broke my system... I did what you said, rebooted, and started the kernel line with nVidia enabled. That worked. I rebooted again and this time chose the one wich blacklisted nVidia... After the boot screen I got a white line at the top of my screen which blinked occasionally (not like a command line environment), nothing more that that. I thought "No problem, I'll just boot the line with nVidia enabled to undo the changes", but I couldn't boot the first line anymore either! Help?

Comment: That sounds like the kernel did not boot at all. If you hold Shift after the BIOS (but before GRUB loads) the menu should show up. When pressing `e`, the lines should look like http://pastebin.com/Ck1H7TwR

Comment: The kernel did boot, I got a boot screen. Anyways, I fixed it. Any other brilliant (better tested) ideas for getting it to work? :p

Comment: I've actually tested this before for blacklisting some modules (wmi,mxm_wmi,nouveau) because an error in the wmi module. The blacklist should have effect only once. Now, is it possible that `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` exists? If yes, remove (or rename) it since it might attempt to load the nvidia driver which is blacklisted for the session.

Comment: It creates that file every time I boot with the NVidia driver enabled.

Comment: That's weird, do you have a startup script that generates the file? `grep -r nvidia /etc/init*`

Comment: No, and for some strange reason the problem happened again just now... On the second boot it worked fine. Even though I removed the `no nvidia` option from GRUB.

Comment: What if you turn `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` into a folder, so that it won't be recreated? Also, what distro version are you running?